# discover class relationships from scenario

Tags: android, uml, class-design, oop

I need to discover the multiplicity and the relation between the following.

Class 1 does functions and sets object1 into class 3.

Class 1 then puts th object into an Intent when it calls class 2. The object in the Intent gets the object from class 3.

When class 2 activity starts it gets the object 1 from the Intent. Class 2 then does functions and sets the object1 back into class 3.

On loading the activity of class 1 it always gets the object1 from the onCreate.

Does anyone know how I can use this in a class diagram and discover multiplicity and show the relationship.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually code what you need then just reverse engineer your code in order to get a class diagram. Multiplicity will automatically be detected from your code.

Comment: @user294000 can I do this in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, you can using Topcased, Papyrus open source or Rational IBM, Omondo, Visual Age using commercial tools.I use personnaly Omondo and really happy with the reverse. Documentation is available at: http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/reverse/reverse/reverse_engineering_example.html . You can download the 30 days evaluation and reverse your project during the evaluation period. Build to unzip is at: http://www.uml2.org/eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32_eclipseUML2.2_package_may2010.zip

Comment: @user294000 Thanks, how can I install this into eclipse using the build path you have shown. Thanks

Comment: The link is for the evaluation build which is a standalone Eclipse 3.5 including EclipseUML Omondo and others needed plugins. I think they don't provide anymore the EclipseUML plugin which could be installed into an existing Eclipse for non paid customer. The reason could be that installing a plugin into an existing workspace could be a nightmare and they don't want to provide support which is more related to plugin correct installation than to EclipseUML. Having hundred of download per day with maybe 10% of plugin installation problem related to Eclipse was certainly a big job for them !!

Comment: I have myself received the plugin and installed it inside my company Helios Eclipse workspace. I had some problems at the beginning but after few emails with the support they told me how to clean my workspace and install correctly all my plugins. Now everyting is fine. Thanks to the omondo support team :-)